# Angular $location how to redirect to absolute URL (not just hash)

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 angular apps (notice the position of `#`)

```
localhost:8888/article#!/[articleId]/view
localhost:8888/article#!/[articleId]/create


localhost:8888/auth#!/signin
localhost:8888/auth#!/signup
```

I use $location to navigate inside apps. For example, if i'm already inside article, calling `$location.path('/' + data._id + '/view')` will go to `/article#!/[data._id]/view`

```
$scope.$on(helper.constant.notificationTypes.data, function(event, data) {
    helper.clearAllThenShowMessage($scope, data, true)
    $location.path('/' + data._id + '/view')
})
```

Now I want to change my code to use absolute path everywhere for some reason. How can I pass in `'/article#!/' + data._id + '/view'` instead?

Also, if it's navigating within the same angular app, I dont want to refresh the page. e.g. `/article#!/[articleId]/view` -> `/auth#!/signin`, refresh page, but `/article#!/[articleId]/view` -> `/article#!/[articleId]/edit`, don't refresh page

Answer (score 0):

So if it's all on the same port then you can do either:

```
href="article#![article[Id]/edit"
```

and:

```
href="auth#!/signin"
```

Drop the "/" at the beginning.